# Hibernate deleting a record from database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a tricky situation which I cannot solve on my own.

Briefly: I'm making a simple **JavaFX** application for a car sale. The database I'm using is **MySQL** and as an ORM framework. I'm using **Hibernate**.

In the table `sales`, I have some foreign keys like (auto, employee, and client) which I need to be stored for every new record to keep track of.

What I want to do is when a new sale record is going to be created, I actually want to delete the auto from its respective table, but this operation fails since that auto has a foreign key constraint on sales table.

I don't want to lose information of deleted auto from autos, I want to store it in another table named `saled_autos`.

Comment: It sounds like you have a design problem. Why would you move the record from one table to another. Just add a field with its status (eg SOLD, FOR_SALE).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I actually thought about that, but I was in hesitation. Now that you suggested that it seems like a good way to go. I'm making a university project and still don't have experience.